# I can't install Puppeteer. I get the same error if I do npm install

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, node-modules

I'm trying to install puppeteer and every time I get the same error, I already installed Chromium and puppeteer-core, my node version is 18.16.0 and my npm version is 9.7.1, anyone has some solution please?

PS: I already tried delete the node_modules and the package-lock.json

```
andres@andres-VirtualBox:~/Documents/theceshop/plat-web-components$ sudo npm install
[sudo] password for andres: 
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/andres/.local/share/Trash/files/plat-web-components/node_modules/puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-06-21T20_50_37_257Z-debug-0.log
andres@andres-VirtualBox:~/Documents/theceshop/plat-web-components$
```

[image]

Comment: What does prevent you from following the last line?

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Answer (score 0):

I used yarn instead `npm instal` and worked in my Ubuntu enviroment